# C# cannot access webservice that requires a client certificate from within the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, client-certificates

I have a webservice on a IIS website that requires a client certificate, my certificate is  self signed and I can access the website from my dev computer without any warning after installing all the certificates issued/required, my problem is that I need to access a webservice from within the server and it's not working, I can do that from my dev machine by loading the certificate pfx file but on the server it will bomb, I already have the application pool the rights to access the certificate on the store but still no go, I appreciate any advice.
Thanks

**On the dev machine this code works:**
    svc.ClientCertificates.Add(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("Certs/MyFile.pfx"), "mypfxpassword"));

**but that codes bombs on the server with:**
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr) at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(....

so I tried this code on the server:
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("Certs/MyFile.pfx"), 
            "mypfxpassword", 
            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            svc.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

**and there's a new error:**
    "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

**I already tried this**
winhttpcertcfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s MyCertName -a "MYMACHINENAME\Name Of App Pool"

**and this**
ICACLS  /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":R

I replaced the parameters on the command with my server paramaters and they executed successfully but still no go with "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.".

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How I got it working.

**Errors:**

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - Could the problem be a proxy
> server?
>
> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
> channel"

**1) IIS**

- Open IIS
- Select Application Pools
- Select your pool
- Click "Advanced Settings"
- Set "Load User Profile" to "True" (mine was set to False)

**2) Code Fix (required cause client certificate is self-signed and .NET doesn't trust that**

- `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`

Code thanks to [this website](http://robertgreiner.com/2013/03/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel/), copied code from *Matt Probstfeld II*'s comment.

Comment: Your code fix is not a very good one, All a server needs to do is give you any certificate and it will accept it. If you are using self signed certificates you should hard-code the fingerprint of the certificate in the client and have it check that.